# How Can I Create Variables From Text and Convert Coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, find, coordinates, simulator

I am aware there are similar questions to mine, but after trying numerous "answers" over several hours I thought my best next step is submit my conundrum here. I respect your time.

After several hours with no success in understanding why my Python script won't work I decided to see if someone could help me. Essentially, the goal is to use the astronomical program, "Stellarium" as a "day and night sky" to practice Celestial Navigation (CelNav) navigating the simulated world of Microsoft Flight Simulator X (FSX). The script actually writes a "startup.ssc" script which initializes Stellarium's date, time, and position.

The process is thus...

1. Use FSX and save a "flight." This creates a *.FLT file which is a text file which saves the complete situation, including time and location.
2. Run the FSXtoStellarium.py
3. Locate the lines of date, time, latitude, longitude, and altitude in the *.FLT text.
4. Read the data into variables.
5. Convert the Degrees(°), Minutes('), Seconds(") (DMS) to Decimal Degrees (DD).
6. Lastly, the script constructs a "startup.ssc" and opens Stellarium at the recorded time and place.

The Problem:
I have not been able to read the DMS into variable(s) correctly nor can I format the DMS into Decimal Degrees (DD). According to the "watches" I set in my IDE (PyScripter), the script is reading in an "int" value I can't decipher instead of the text string of the DMS (Example: W157° 27' 23.20").

Here are some excerpts of the file and script.

---

### HMS Bounty.FLT

```
Various lines of data above...

[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
Altitude=+000004.93

Various lines of data below...
EOF
```

---

### FSXtoStellarium.py

```
Various lines of script above...

# find lat & Lon in the file
start = content.find("SimVars.0")
latstart = content.find("Latitude=")
latend = content.find("Latitude=",latstart+1)
longstart = content.find("Longitude=",start)
longend = content.find(",",longstart)

# convert to dec deg
latitude = float(content[longend+1:latend])/120000
longitude = float(content[longstart+10:longend])/120000

Various lines of script below...
```

So, what am I missing?

FYI - I am an old man who gets confused. My professional career was in COBOL/DB2/CICS, but you can consider me a Python newbie (it shows, right?). :)

Your help s greatly appreciated and I will gladly provide any additional information.

Calvin

Comment: Should `latitude = float(content[longend+1:latend])/120000` instead be `latitude = float(content[latstart+len("Latitude=":latend])/120000`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have corrected the code. Oops! Throwing a syntax error. FYI - I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and cut to the chase — we don't need to know all the irrelevant details.

Comment: @martineau - I actually tried to do so, but I need to try again. Like I stated, I respect the time and effort you all exercise. I tried to honor that. I have looked at your link. It is difficult for me to understand, but I will try to digest it. There are some things I don't understand, but will try and follow the guidelines and repost. Do I need to repost in a comment like this or edit my OP. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, you need to. Distill the problem down to its essence and post the *minimum* amount of code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get from the text file (with multiple input lines) all the way to Decimal Degrees in python 2.7:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
content='''
[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
'''

latKey = "Latitude="
longKey = "Longitude="

latstart = content.index(latKey) + len(latKey)
latend = content.find('"', latstart) + 1
longstart = content.find(longKey, latend) + len(longKey)
longend = content.find('"', longstart) + 1

lat = content[latstart:latend]
long = content[longstart:longend]

print()
print('lat ', lat)
print('long ', long)

deg, mnt, sec = [float(x[:-1]) for x in lat[1:].split()]
latVal = deg + mnt / 60 + sec / 3600

deg, mnt, sec = [float(x[:-1]) for x in long[1:].split()]
longVal = deg + mnt / 60 + sec / 3600

print()
print('latVal ', latVal)
print('longVal ', longVal)
```

Explanation:

- we start with a multi-line string, `content`
- the first `index()` call finds the start position of the substring `"Latitude="` within `content`, to which we add the length of `"Latitude="` since what we care about is the characters following the `=` character
- the second `index()` call searches for the 'seconds' character `"` (which marks the end of the `Latitude` substring), to which we add one (for the length of the `"`)
- the third `index()` call does for `Longitude=` something similar to what we did for latitude, except it starts at the position `latend` since we expect `Longitude=` to follow the latitude string following `Latitude=`
- the fourth `index()` call seeks the end of the longitude substring and is completely analogous to the second `index()` call above for latitude
- the assignment to `lat` uses square bracket slice notation for the list `content` to extract the substring from the end of `Latitude=` to the subsequent `"` character
- the assignment to `long` is analogous to the previous step
- the first assignment to `deg, mnt, sec` is assigning a `tuple` of 3 values to these variables using a list comprehension:

  - split `lat[1:]`, which is to say lat with the leading cardinal direction character `N` removed, into space-delimited tokens `21°`, `20'` and `47.36"`
  - for each token, `x[:-1]` uses slice notation to drop the final character which gives strings `21`, `20` and `47.36`
  - `float()` converts these strings to numbers of type `float`
- the assignment to `latVal` does the necessary arithmetic to calculate a quantity in decimal degrees using the degrees, minutes and seconds stored in `deg, mnt, sec`.
- the treatment of `long` to get to `longVal` is completely analogous to that for `lat` and `latVal` above.

---

Output:

```
lat  N21° 20' 47.36"
long  W157° 27' 23.20"

latVal  21.34648888888889
longVal  157.45644444444443
```

Comment: Thank you, @constantstranger. I have been working with your code and guidance for a couple of hours. To be honest, I never expected this level of help, but I sure appreciate it. I don't fully understand the syntax, so I am taking some time to see if the light bulb will turn on.

Comment: Glad I could help, and feel free to ask if there’s anything specific you need help with in my answer. Also, please consider marking my answer “accepted”.

Comment: Okay, I think I have a shaky handle on the code you offered, but only in the controlled environment of having the "content" in the code. The data I am attempting to extract the lat/long from is 522 lines of dynamic data which is constantly changing.  For this I exchanged

 content='''
[SimVars.0]
Latitude=N21° 20' 47.36"
Longitude=W157° 27' 23.20"
'''

with...

(see next comment)

Comment: # Change the directory on the next line to point to SaveData.map in your saved game directory.
savefolder = "C:\\Users\\cjw\\Documents\\Flight Simulator X Files"

# Set the Stellarium directory
stellocation = "C:\\Stellarium"

####### End Editable locations #########

savedgame = savefolder +"\\HMS Bounty.FLT"

def nn(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        num = "0" + x
    else:
        num = x
    return num


# read savegame.
f = open(savedgame,'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()

and it worked! I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Oops! Sorry for the run-on formatting. I don't know how to format code, bullets, etc. in these comments yet. :(

Comment: Q: Does the logic of the index statements have to be chronological/contiguous in a sequential flow or can I bounce around in the data file (HMS Bounty.FLT) at will?

Now I have the location code figured out with your guidance, I need to do the same for the time (year, day, etc.). I think I can tackle this using your code offering/explanations as a model.

Comment: If you have `content` loaded up with the full 522 lines of text data, you can call [`index()`[(https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) using any `start` position (second argument) you like (`index()` also has an optional `end` argument if you think that may be useful).

Comment: Thank you. I (we) have successfully coded the script and it does correctly format the "Startup.ssc" script which initializes the initial position which correctly matches my global position on the FSX world. Although this works right, CelNav requires exact location and time (to the second) to use the celestial canopy to pinpoint one's location on our Big Blue Marble. So, now I'm off to code the time entry for the Startup.ssc for Stellarium. FYI - preliminary tests show I can use the same code logic for time as I did for the location code. (continued)

Comment: The only hurdle I see is FSX outputs time as year-days-hours-minutes-seconds. (Note there are no months in FSX format). Stellarium requires a year-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds for input. The coding for the input for the Python script and the output for the Stellarium startup script  are (finally) straightforward. The only cerebral challenge is the conversion logic, bit I think I can handle that. I'll check back if I hit a snag